# Heroku keys add command does not add keys

Tags: git, heroku

Was trying to deploy a python app on heroku using heroku git and I had a public key error so I tried to create a new one from scratch using

```
heroku keys:add
```

And it returned this error

```
EACCES: spawn EACCES
```

At first I thought this was a permission problem so I went with `sudo`, but this also did nothing. Nothing has happened even after fiddling a bit with granting user with write access in the `~/.ssh` folder. Does anyone know what's the proper procedure to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I fixed this problem by removing it via snap

`sudo snap remove heroku`

and installing it using second way [(ubuntu-12-and-below)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#ubuntu-12-and-below)

`wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`